# How to create multiple Views for the same Window in Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, cocoa-bindings

I have application that has one Application delegate, and one Window. I have different classes that running threads, etc. When I'm sending  NSWindow *window pointer to that classes or function, and trying to change VIew , [window setcontentView//something]. It doesn't display anything ,what I am doing wrong ? What is the easiest way to have one window, and different classes, and change that Content for that window, from different classes. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean different classes? Do you have multiple view controllers?

Comment: No I have different classes for the Threads. I have just one View Controller, and application delegate, I need to change my UI controls from the thread. When I do [window setcontentView] is not working

Comment: What UI controls do you have, are they on the window, and what data do you want them to show from your thread?

Comment: Are you executing all UI-related operations on the main thread? That’s a requirement in Cocoa.

Comment: Ok thanks I will execute UI operations on the main thread. But How can I do it? Because I can't get return value from the thread.

Comment: Use properties to set values in the thread and read them in the main thread, but make sure the properties are nonatomic. When you finished with your calculations in the thread and set the property call [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateUI) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO]. This selector will be called in the main thread. All you need to do now is to refresh your controls, let's say - (void)updateUI { [myTextField setStringValue:self.myNonatomicStrinfValue] };

Answer (score 0):

At first you should implement your UIApplicationDelegate method didFinishLaunchingWithOptions something like this:

```
MainViewController *mainController = [[[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainView" bundle:nil] autorelease];
navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mainController];
navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
[self.window addSubview:navigationController.view];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Later you can create different UIViewController instances and push them to UINavigationController object.

Comment: Thanks.Mine is MAC OS Application, not IOS. How can I push instances to UINavigationController?

Comment: Cocoa doesn't have UINAvigationController